# Programmatically logout in iOS application

Tags: ios, ipad, authentication, uiviewcontroller, logout

My iOS application contains login page. And after entering the app there is a logout button. When a user presses the logout button programmatically I want to show login page again as if the user is logging first time. Could you please suggest how I could implement this in my iPad application.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how your login mechanism works? If you [tell us what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), we can be more helpful in our answers.

Comment: Sorry to say that i am not aware that i have to accept the answere. Really sorry for that. Will accept answers now onwards. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for fixing your accept-rate. Now back to your issue. We need to know how your login / session management works to help you out here. Actually, it seems as if you have to find out yourself as that would most likely allow you to solve the task already.

Comment: My login screen validates credentials using NSConnection type and as soon as authentication success i am popping out the loginviewcontroller and navigates to homepage. I did work around my problem by just creating the loginviewcontroller when user press Logout button push it to navigation stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this in my app. I have a tabbarcontroller that i use for logged in users. When they log out (or for first time use) I message the appDelegate that removes the tab bar from the window and makes the login view the root view. Once logged in, that view is replaced by the tab bar controller.

I even go a bit further. On each switch I totally release all the other objects, and so I know for sure that when user sees any of these views it's completely 'fresh' and only uses the defaults for anything custom to that user.

Comment: Yes David you are right. This would be one of the best approach. My app is ARC enabled so I am just reusing the navigation controller stack so that i don't create the viewcontrollers multiple times.

Comment: As stated, the advantage of recreating them is that you purge the objects, so you know for sure that they are in a pristine just created state. That has advantages, and the time consumed is just a one time occurrence.

Comment: in a Single View application, can't we just unwind segue to the firs/initial view controller, erasing all the data, related to the Logged in user account? isn't that a good thing to do, in storyboard based App.?

Comment: @Vishman while you are correct, this is not the issue. Suppose you have a tab bar - you don't want to just unwind to the first VC in one of the tabs - you want the whole thing gone. Now, there are other ways to do this - my suggestion is one that worked for me. All my TabBarControllers were subclasses that retained some info, so in my solution I knew I was started fresh - my app supported a "Wipe this account" action.

Comment: Actually I had to faced to implement my above described comment few hours back. The Only thing I did that is, not knowing that yours is the good thing to do, but my lack of knowledge in Code and iOS Framework wise to implement the scenario which you have described in your answer and in your comment! :) I would be glad and really thankful if you can guide us with a coding sample within Stackoverflow or in your wordpress blog!
Thanks for the guidance in advance!
#Respect!